# Does the standard allow to rebind the allocator-type given with a

Tags: c++

If you have a container and a given allocator is it mandated that the standard-libary always uses this allocator for T ? Consider a `list<T>`, where, when the given allocator is used, it would be necesssary to allocate the list node object and the T object separately, having a node object pointing to the T object. There's `rebind_alloc` to "cast" the allocator to another type so that you could specialize that allocator for internal types the container uses. Is this allowed or even used by the standard libraries ?
There's s similar question with an answer where someone said that he *thinks* that the container behave like that, but not with a definite reference.

Comment: A container will use the allocator you give it in the constructor. I don't get your question.

Comment: "it would be necesssary to allocate the list node object and the T object separately" That's not how `std::list` is usually implemented, but there is no guarantee. "Is this allowed or even used" Yes and yes.

Comment: @Nelfeal: Consider a container like unordered_map. It has a Bucket-List and the nodes. That are different types which must go through the same allocator, specialized with different types.

Answer (score 0):

> Unless otherwise specified, all containers defined in this Clause obtain memory using an allocator [...] A copy of this allocator is used for any memory allocation and element construction performed, by these constructors and by all member functions

[source](https://eel.is/c++draft/containers#container.reqmts-64).

Comment: std::allocator requires a templated copy-constructor with a source type of an allocator of the same type with an allocated type that can be arbitrarily. That allows to cast the allocator type to a different allocated type. There's rebind_alloc that makes an allocator specialized for another allocated type from the same allocator.

Comment: @DouglasQuaid: Yes; what's your point? They're *copies* of the original allocator.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's rather a conversion of the original allocator because the type of allocator is different.